# Python Selenium - Can't extract text from item using "driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME "class name"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the text content of a `<span>` using the CLASS_NAME method, and even though the `<span>` is the only element with that class, when I assign the text of the span to a variable and print said variable, what gets printed is a return line.

The structure of the page is the following:

• There is the most outer `<div>` that contain basically any information I need, which I was able top identify with the following snippet:

```
#Only One with this classed
main_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='am-appointments am-section']")
```

Inside of previous `<div>` there a variable number of other  that compartmentalize the informations I am seeking on a date basis, so each day has it own day. , which I was able top identify with the following snippet:

```
child_divs = main_div.find_elements(By.XPATH,"./div[not(contains(@class, 'am-appointments-list-head') or contains(@class, 'am-pagination am-section'))]")
```

with the former command I extracted a list of these child , each one of them has again a variable number of  and each on of these contains the informations I need.
So I ran a for loop like this:

```
for child_div in child_divs:
    appointments=child_div.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='am-appointments-list']//div[@class='el-collapse']//div[contains(@class, 'el-collapse-item am-appointment am-back-appointment') or contains(@class, 'el-collapse-item am-appointment am-front-appointment')]")
    
    for appointment in appointments:
        phone=appointment.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "am-appointment-data-phone")
        phone_text=phone.text
```

I created again a list of all the  inside each child_div, and ran again the loop, to find and extract the phone number from a `<span>` that has the following features:

```
<span class="am-appointment-data-phone">+393314569013</span>
```

Even though the `<span>` I am targeting in this final step is the only item with this class, the script doesn't print anything. So I guess somehow doesn't get assigned to the variable `phone_text`.
The `<span>` I am targeting is part of an animation, you click the button, the module expands and it's visible, or maybe there's some interference with Javascript ?
I really don't understand what could be the issue. Thank you for anyone who can help!

Comment: Try printing `len(child_divs)` and `len(appointments)`

Comment: If the span is created dynamically, or the class is added dynamically, it might not be found when you're trying to get it.

Comment: In case the <span> is created dynamically, which is very very probable, is there a workaround ?

Comment: You need to emulate the actions that create it. Selenium can wait for an element to exist.

Comment: I have tried with no success...
I recorded this quick video: https://youtu.be/6TMuakYTj9w if you could give me even just a direction to look into it'd be fantastic...

Comment: In general this kind of thing requires reverse engineering the web site's JavaScript.